# Animations best practices

Tags: ember.js

What is the best approach if we want to do animations with ember.js ?

By Example, I would like to animate some view with "standart" animation (rotate, slide, flip)

I have discovered the following info but I do not know if something better is existing ?

http://www.scoop.it/t/develop/p/1970906412/ember-js-animations-with-jquery-animate-blog-dynopia

https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the best practice is probably to use the ember-animated-outlet plugin. https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet.

An API for animated transitions will probably be a part of Ember 1.1, but in the interim the Ember core team has expressed support for the 
ember-animated-outlet" project.